# Why do I get "invalid 'type' (character) of argument" using xtab() in R

Tags: r

The error...

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

...is not new and I can find a lot of SO questions about it. But because of low quality MWE's I'm not able to fit the answers to my own problem.

I'm interested not only in a quick code based solution but in a deeper understand why this error happens.

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
    gender = sample(c("female", "male"), 100, replace = TRUE),
    foo = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = TRUE),
    bar = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

xtabs(gender ~ foo, data=df)
```

Comment: The right side of the formula is for the classifying variable or variables, the left side is for defining counts. The values in the "gender" column aren't numeric and therefore  not valid. Does `xtabs(foo ~ gender, data = df)` return the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side of the formula is usually empty.  If you have something there, it should be a vector or matrix of counts.  You have `gender` there, which is a character variable and the error message comes when `xtabs()` tries to interpret it as counts.

So to fix this, just put the two factors on the right hand side:

```
xtabs(~ gender + foo, data=df)
```

BTW, even though neither one of those columns is actually a "factor", `xtabs()` will automatically convert them.